# jQuery slide toggle - jumping issue on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to apply the expand and close when it's on mobile screen sizes.
I'm facing with bouncing issue at the moment. I tried to play around with hide and show but didn't work.

```
$(window).resize(function(){  
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $("#header").click(function () {
      $("#content-services").slideToggle(500);
    });
  }
});
```

On desktop it is wide open - so there's no need to apply the expand / collapse on desktop

[image]

I'd like the script for expand and collapse to be working smaller screen sizes -

[image]

Comment: how do you set the `width` of `content-services` ? I mean in `px` ? or `% ,auto` ?

Comment: @rory-h Please create a jsfiddle with exact scenario.

Comment: @Shiladitya Please do not recommend users to share code from external links. Those links can become unavailable and other future users searching for this problem won't be able to access that code. There is a StackOverflow code snippet available ( Ctrl + M or the <> button in the top toolbar when writing/editing a question or an answer )

Comment: @MihaiT My mistake, I mentioned jsfiddle, but the intension was to was see the code (not just jsfiddle)

Comment: @UsmanRana the width of content-services is set with px. there's min-width:300px tied to content-services